# How do I block XInput / DirectInput in games?

Tags: controllers

In some games, the ability to remap the controller is non-existent and the default mapping is mismatched with my controller. I want to know how to prevent those games (commonly running DirectX) from detecting that I have a controller connected while I use Xpadder to do the remapping myself?

Comment: Have you tried [x360ce](https://code.google.com/p/x360ce/) instead? I use it on DirectX games without any issue

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, my laptop was being repaired the past few days. Anyway, I know about x360ce but I've found Xpadder to be far more flexible in terms of mapping.

Answer (score 1):

On some controllers, they will have a switch that switches between XInput and DirectInput. If the games are using DirectX, usually they will be using XInput, as stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417014(v=vs.85).aspx),

> Note  Use of legacy DirectInput is not recommended, and DirectInput is not available for Windows Store apps.

The site also is more favoring towards using XInput, at least for DirectX games. If you flip that switch to DirectX, and XPadder supports mapping DirectX controls, you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like DirectInput can be blocked using HidGuardian (https://github.com/ViGEm/HidGuardian)

It will apparently soon be replaced by HidHide which will also support blocking XInput.